# How to get all the input values in a form using Selenium

Tags: forms, selenium, automation

Let's take a form of student details;
I want take take all these input data into a `List` or `Set`.
Please check the attached picture and give me any suggestions.

[image: Studendata]

Comment: Input data means do you want to get only  all input box elements value into list or all elements value like as input,select etc?? And need to share HTML code as well

Answer (score 0):

To get the inputs and the select you can use a selector like:

```
input, select option[selected=selected]
```

to get only the input use css selector for input tag:

```
input
```

to get also the selected inputs you could use:

```
input[type=radio], input[type*=text], select option[selected=selected]
```

you will need to add an extra attribute for the radio input to get only the selected ones, you might need to do dome updates for the select also.

These selectors are only an estimate of what you need since the html is not available.